# Confute consistency of a difficult function

Tags: calculus

How can i proof that

[image]

is not a continuous fuction?

Thanks.

Comment: Find a point $x$ where the left and right limits are different.

Comment: Wolphram Alpha showed me that in x = 0 the function has a jump. But how can I show this with left and right limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\lfloor x \rfloor=0$ if $0\leq x <1$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor=-1$ if $-1\leq x<0$. So if you consider $\lim\limits_{x\to 0-}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}{f(x)}=0$ which are not equal and hence $f$ is not continuous at $0$.
In particular it can be shown that $f$ need not be continuous at integer points, which uses the fact that $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is discontinuous at integer points.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $$lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x) = 0+\frac{(0-(-1))^4}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$f(0)=0.$$
Then, $f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

One contradiction of continuity is enough

$$f(1)=1$$

$$lim_{x\to 1^-}=1+\frac{(1-0)^4}{2}=\frac32$$

Comment: This may induce some mistakes. Why do you put (-1) instead of 1?

Comment: @Leafar you are right. thanks. fixed

Comment: This is true since we have ^4. But you know what I want to say =)